# TestFlight like service for released Apps

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there a service similar to TestFlight, for iPhone apps released onto the App Store. So that if the app crashes I get the crash logs. And where if a certain point in the app is reached  (e.g. a "catch" statement, where I hope the user never gets to), it triggers a message on the service (like the TestFlight checkpoints, but less invasive).

I'm not looking for full on Analytics as I don't believe Apps should be that stalkerish.

Do Apple provide any similar/basic services? Such as telling you when your app crashes.

I know users can submit bugs on the App Store, but this is too much effort for the majority of users.

Answer (score 2):

[QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/)/[HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/) is a big one for this. I know a couple of people who host their own QuincyKit instances to get full crash report data and aggregation from their shipped apps.

Comment: Is there anything more simple and free-er?

Comment: Quincykit is Free, as it is fully Open Source. So you can host it on your own server. HockeyApp adds server side symbolication, grouping of similar crashes by source code and more. Whatever you use, make sure to use something based on PLCrashReporter, since that is the only safe way to catch crashes on iOS. See http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html

Comment: Yes but then I have to find and pay for a host, and if the user happens to see the app communicating with some weird domain name, I know I wouldn't be too happy

Comment: They would only see the domain nee, if they sniff the traffic, which isn't easy for most users. HockeyApp has a one month trial and indie plan for $10 a month for up to 5 apps. Free service always means someone else pays, but who and from which money and with which goal? :)

Comment: The fact that TestFlight is even free is insane, you're not going to find a free service to do analytics like this. You either need to host it yourself or shell out.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg, I don't expect Analytics for free, I don't really want them, just the ability to send a message from the app if something goes wrong (e.g. if the data returned from a download is not recognised, it sends a message to a server, where I can see how many times it has been reported, and if I need to modify the app)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you consider "full on Analytics", but [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) (free) allows you to report errors from your app. The only thing you *must* track is a session, which records when the user starts (and exits) your app.

To track errors, you just wire up an uncaught exception handler and then send whatever error information you'd like. From the Flurry API docs:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
  [FlurryAnalytics logError:@"Uncaught" message:@"Crash!" exception:exception];
}
```

We've used this method in several apps and it works well.